# Finite topological spaces minimal basic open set

Tags: general-topology

in finite topological spaces what is the relation between f(Ux) and Uf(x) where Ux is the minimal baisc open set at x ? where f  is  a function from finite space to the other

Comment: Do you want $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: ok thank good but now if f is not continuous @danial Rust

Comment: since  there is lemma in j.p May  lecture note there is Lemma

Comment: and there is step not clear to me

Comment: I think if there is more context to this question, then you should add it to your post as otherwise my answer might not be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous, then $U_x\subseteq f^{-1}(U_{f(x)})$ because $f^{-1}(U_{f(x)})$ is open and $U_x$ is minimal, and so $f(U_x)\subseteq U_{f(x)}$. If $f(U_x)$ is open, then we would also have $U_{f(x)}\subseteq f(U_x)$ because $U_{f(x)}$ is minimal. So, if $f$ is both continuous and open, then we can say that $f(U_x)=U_{f(x)}$.

If you drop these conditions on $f$, then I'm not sure what kind of relationship you could hope to have for an arbitrary function as the topology on the space doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Danial Rust there is a step in this link http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/FiniteSpaces.pdf lemma 2.2 page 3 the last step how he get that Uy subset of V?

Comment: @TahaGumaelturki $U_{f(y)}$ is defined to be the intersection of the open sets containing $f(y)$, given that $V$ is defined to be an open set containing $f(y)$, it must hold that $U_{f(y)}$ is a subset of $V$.

Comment: @Danial Rust sorry I write my question in wrong way how he get that Uf(y) will be a subset of f^-1(V) can you make it clear to me than you